# collection_select show multiple object attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In addition to showing the challenge's `name`. I also want to show its `deadline` next to the `name`.

It would look like this for example:

```
Visit London 09/09/16
Make $1,000,000 10/15/18
Knit a Scarf 01/11/19
```

Instead of just this:

[image]

```
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, current_user.challenges.order(:deadline),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method `name_with_deadline` in `challenge.rb`

```
def name_with_deadline
  "#{name} #{deadline}"
end
```

and then make use of this method as label in the collection.

```
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, current_user.challenges.order(:deadline),:id, :name_with_deadline, include_blank: true %>
```

The `name_with_deadline` method will called for every object in the collection to retrieve the label text.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a virtual attribute to you model like below:

```
def name_deadline
 "#{name} #{deadline}"
end
```

**collection_select:**

```
<%= f.collection_select :challenge_id, current_user.challenges.order(:deadline),:id,:name_deadline, include_blank: true %>
```